# Different between =0/1 and 0

Tags: excel

imagine there's a task assigned.

if there's no task, the value will be 0.

if there was 1 unfinished task, it will be 0/1.

some user doesn't always fill with x/y. For example, it can be 50%, 20%.

the formula of the result is Key divided by Plan (Key/Plan).

| Key | Plan | Result wanted | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0% | 30% | 100% | 0 mean no task, so result should be 100% |
| =0/1 | 50% | 0% | 1 unfinished task, it will be 0% |
| 10% | 20% | 50% | 10% of 20% task finished will be 50% |

I can't solve it because 0/1 is also 0. is there any formula to identify that problem?

I've tried using if statement but it can't identify between 0 and 0/1 so the result is always 0%.

Comment: This is not very clear. What have you tried and what result are you seeking?

Comment: yes, if there's no task, the user may input 0 as the key but the result should be 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is a shot in the dark, but I guess that the inputs are always **values** except in the case **if there was 1 unfinished task, it will be 0/1.** where they then input **a formula like** `=0/1`

You could do something like this:

[image]

The formula I got in F2 ( and drag down) is:

```
=IF(ISFORMULA(A2);0;IF(A2=0;1;A2/B2))
```

And then applu % format to cell to get desired output.

This is kind of fragile, because it depends that users enter always values (formula only when `=0/x`

[ISFORMULA function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/isformula-function-e4d1355f-7121-4ef2-801e-3839bfd6b1e5) is available only from Excel 2013, so if you got an older version, this won't work.